# perl - File::Basename->fileparse returns "File::Basename"

Tags: perl, fileparse

For some reason my code is doing this wierd thing where `fileparse` only prints (literally) `File::Basename`

```
 use strict;
 use warnings 'all';
 use File::Basename;

 ...

 my $fileName = File::Basename->fileparse($filePath);
 print("$filePath\n");
 print("$fileName\n");
```

And output is:

```
a/b/c/d.bin
File::Basename
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `fileparse` is not a method; it is a function.  This function is exported by default, so you actually want to do

```
use File::Basename;
my $fileName = fileparse($filePath);
```

You have used is as a method call. Here `File::Basename->fileparse($filePath)` is equivalent to

```
fileparse("File::Basename", $filePath)
```

because in a method invocation, the *invocant* (usually an object; here the package name) becomes the first argument. This is wrong, as it treats `"File::Basename"` as the path to parse, and the following arguments as a list of valid suffixes.

If you want to use the `fileparse` function without exporting it to your namespace, you could

```
use File::Basename (); # note empty parens that supress the import
File::Basename::fileparse(...); # use fully qualified name
```